# Neo4j ERROR while starting -- invalid date string

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to install neo4j unix version on my Linux Mint 17.xx.  I followed the instructions as given in their download page.  After extracting the contents to a local folder, I tried to run the neo4j console. Here is where it fails to start with the below message:

```
rvnath@rvnath-pc /usr/local/neo4j-community-3.0.4/bin $ ./neo4j console
Starting Neo4j.
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
२०१६-०८-२७ ०४:५४:०१.२३०+0000 INFO  No SSL certificate found, generating a self-signed certificate..
२०१६-०८-२७ ०४:५४:०१.५६२+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on address is a hostname and port invalid date string: Unparseable date: "gkfnhnfjkjfgGMT+00:00"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid date string: Unparseable date: "gkfnhnfjkjfgGMT+00:00"
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1UTCTime.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERUTCTime.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Time.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.security.ssl.Certificates.createSelfSignedCertificate(Certificates.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.createKeyStore(AbstractNeoServer.java:389)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.init(AbstractNeoServer.java:173)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:186)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
rvnath@rvnath-pc /usr/local/neo4j-community-3.0.4/bin $
```

- It says it is failing because of unparseable date.
- Is it failing because my locale is not english (it is Hindi /India)?  And hence, it is unable to parse the date string correctly?
- How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a bug in BouncyCastle, as the [code in Neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.0.4/community/bolt/src/main/java/org/neo4j/bolt/security/ssl/Certificates.java#L100) doesn't seem to pass a date string in the parameters. It could be trying to parse a date using a hard-coded locale, instead of the current one, which makes it read

> gkfnhnfjkjfgGMT+00:00

instead of what can be seen in your log:

> २०१६-०८-२७ ०४:५४:०१.५६२+0000

You can try forcing the locale for Neo4j by setting the `LC_ALL` environment variable for its execution:

```
LC_ALL=en_US ./neo4j.sh console
```

or

```
LC_ALL=C ./neo4j.sh console
```

Alternatively, export the variable before starting the script:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US # Or "C"
./neo4j.sh console
```